# Getting a TypeError,takes no argument ,,Please anyone help on this

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror, init

```
class Student:
 def checkpassfail(self):
    if self.marks>30:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def __init__(self,names,marks):
       self.names=names
       self.marks=marks

student1= Student('jack',87)
print(student1.names)
print(student1.marks)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in the class student, the constructor should be defined like this

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self,names,marks):
         self.names=names 
         self.marks=marks
    def checkpassfail(self):
        if self.marks>30:
            return True
        else:
            return False

student1= Student('jack',87) 
if student1.checkpassfail():
    print(student1.names)
    print(student1.marks)
```